# Getting a blank page after starting Angular 10.0.3 app on localhost before deploying to Heroku

Tags: angular, heroku, frontend, command-line-interface, angular10

I'm getting a blank page on testing my Angular 10.0.3 app. Here the
**server.js:**

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.use(express.static('./src'));
app.get('/*', (req, res) =>
    res.sendFile('index.html', {root: './src'}),
);

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "fsdoblakoangular",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~10.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "~10.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "~10.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "~10.0.3",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.5",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1000.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~10.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.9.5"
  }
}
```

**angular.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "fsdoblakoangular": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/fsdoblakoangular",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "fsdoblakoangular:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "fsdoblakoangular:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "fsdoblakoangular:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "fsdoblakoangular:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "fsdoblakoangular:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }},
  "defaultProject": "fsdoblakoangular"
}
```

When I started via `ng serve --open` it's work fine. But when I want to launch it via `node server.js` from directory of project - I get a blank page.

I'm using [this](https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-deploy-your-angular-9-app-to-heroku-in-minutes-51d171c2f0d) article and used a repo from the bottom on it.
I think what the problem with paths - scripts cannot compiling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's stupid, but after changing `sctipts -  "start": "ng serve"` in my `package.json` file, i forgot to build the project.

Comment: You sure, that did solve the error because that is default setting?